# TypeError: string indices must be integers. Код на Python

Tags: python, list, type-error

У меня есть такой код:

```
async with session.post('https://example_link.ru', json=data) as response:
    obj = await response.json()
    try:
        return obj["data"][0]
    except IndexError or TypeError or ValueError:
        obj = str('Пусто')
        return obj
```

В конечном итоге я вытаскиваю из obj нужные мне значения таким образом:

```
a = response[0]["adv"]["price"]
```

или

```
b = response[0]["advertiser"]["nickName"]
```

Но если получается, что в списке нет таких элементов, то есть берется не ***obj["data"][0]***, а ***str('Пусто')*** и, как я понимаю, тогда запрос выглядит примерно так:

```
a = Пусто[0][0]["adv"]["price"]
```

Что, верноятно, является неверным запросом и получается *TypeError: string indices must be integers*

Я пробовал делать так:

```
async with session.post('https://example_link.ru', json=data) as response:
    obj = await response.json()
    try:
        return obj["data"][0]["adv"]["price"] #добавил ["adv"]["price"]
    except IndexError or TypeError or ValueError:
        obj = str('Пусто')
        return obj
```

И потом:

```
a = response[0]
```

И так всё работает. Когда в списке нет элемента, то пишется "Пусто". Но проблема в том, что в таком случае я не могу вытаскивать значения для b, в котором они находятся не в **["adv"]["price"]**, а в **["advertiser"]["nickName"]**

Answer (score 0):

Зачем так сложно. В случае ошибки возвращайте `None` и проверяйте результат на этот `None`:

```
    ...
    except IndexError or TypeError or ValueError:
        return None
...

if result is None:
    # обработка ошибки
else:
    # тут берёте какие хотите поля от полноценного результата
```

Ну или если хотите можете и "Пусто" возвращать и проверять, что вернулась строка, а не что-то более сложное:

```
if isinstance(result, str):
    # обработка ошибки
else:
    # тут берёте какие хотите поля от полноценного результата
```

Comment: Здравствуйте. Правильно делаю?         if result is None:
            obj = str('Пусто')
            return obj
        else:
            return obj["data"][0] Просто так выдается ошибка a = response[0]["adv"]["price"]
TypeError: 'NameError' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Нет, я имел ввиду, что **вместо** `str('Пусто')` возвращать `None`, а вот выше, где вы обрабатываете то, что получили, уже делать проверки. Хотя может я не совсем понял, что у вас происходит, где вы второй раз данные достаёте.

Answer (score 0):

Всем, кто будет здесь позже. Я так и не понял как исправить это средствами Python, поэтому пошел на крайние меры:

```
    except IndexError or TypeError or ValueError:
        obj = {'adv': {'price': 'Пусто'}, 'advertiser': { 'nickName': 'Пусто'}}
        return obj
```

То есть иммитировал результат json запроса в ошибку. Так всё работает, хоть метод и костыльный